Two balls connected to string, one on table with no friction, spinning, and one is dangling through a hole in the table. specific question in the body
There are two balls connected to a string. One is on a table and the other is dangling on the string through a hole in the middle of the table. The one on the table is spinning around the table in a constant radius.
To make the ball on the table spin slower but the radius of the spinning motion stay the same how should the masses of the two balls change.
Please answer my question!

This question requires very basic physics to start with :
Take the mass of ball on table as $m_t$ and the dangling one as $m_d$, radius made by ball on table as $R$ and its spinning velocity as $v$ and tension on string as $T$.
Now we know that the string is of constant length so we need to keep in mind the constraint that both masses, if moved (dangling ball vertically and ball on table towards or away from the hole), will move with same velocity or acceleration. Since we need to keep the radius of $ball_t$ constant, both masses must not move (as such : dangling ball vertically and ball on table towards or away from the hole).
Now we can balance forces :
$$m_d g = T$$
$$ T = { m_t v^2 \over R }  $$
Hence $$m_d g = {m_t v^2\over R} $$
$$v = \sqrt {m_d g R \over m_t} $$
So from here we can infer that if we decrease $v$ and keep $R$ constant, we should decrease $m_d$ and increase $m_t$ accordingly.
